# travelport UAPI with xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, travelport-api

I am trying to use TravelPort UAPI in my Xamarin.Android application.
I have a sample C# project from TravelPort. And I have added that sample project in my Xamarin.Android solution.

https://github.com/Travelport/travelport-uapi-tutorial-c-sharp/tree/master/ConsoleApplication1

But I am unable to use classes of that sample project in my Xamarin Android classes(activities).

I want to ask how should I consume classes from that sample project in my Xamarin.Android application??? As I am unable to include the service references directly in xamarin android project

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean that "I am unable to use classes for that sample project". What is wrong?

Comment: I am trying to use classes from that sample project in my Android Activity. I have also added reference to that project and made the class public but still I unable to use it and make objects of that class.

Comment: You are not making yourself clear on what goes wrong.

Comment: The problem is that there are still errors when I try to use those classes like "There is no such class. Have to tried adding references to the project?" something like that. meaning that there are compiler errors when using those classes in my Xamarin.Android activities

Comment: Well there are a lot of service references in the project you link to. Did you add them as well?

Comment: Thank you for your time helping me. 

Is there any direct way to add service references to android project?
If there is please guide me. That will help me alot :)

Comment: Right click your project and choose add service... This is getting too chatty. Open separate issues for separate specific questions.

Comment: But there is only web reference. There is no option to service reference